# Why can I not use custom selected attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use custom "selected" attribute in my HTML and jQuery always returns wrong values of this attribute. I know, that "selected" is using in options tag, but why can I not use it in other tags? Just see the example: http://jsfiddle.net/SE7FB/8/

```
<div class="category" selected="false">First</div>
<div class="category" selected="false">Second</div>
<div id="tester" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; float: right; background-color: black;"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".category").click(function () {
    $("#tester").css("background-color", "rgb(" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + "," + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + "," + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ")");
    $("#tester").append("<p>" + $(this).attr("selected") + "</p>");
    if ($(this).attr("selected") == "true") {
        $(this).css("background-color", "transparent");
        $(this).attr("selected", "false");
    } else if ($(this).attr("selected") == "false") {
        $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
        $(this).attr("selected", "true");
    }
});
```

Comment: The jsfiddle "Tidy Up" button is super-useful.

Comment: jQuery takes pains to make sure that certain special attributes "behave themselves", and "selected" is one of those attributes.  You're setting it to the *strings* "true" and "false" instead of the boolean constants `true` and `false`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why i cant use it in other tags?

Because it's not valid HTML. And then, browsers will behave unexpectedly.

If you want to use custom attributes, use `data-*` ones:

```
<div class="category" data-selected="false">First</div>
$(".category").data('selected'); // get
$(".category").data('selected', value); // set
```

Links:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes
- http://api.jquery.com/data/
- http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#custom-data-attribute

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't, I think, that it "doesn't work" *per se*, merely that it works in a slightly unexpected way.

For instance, if we modify your HTML slightly:

```
<div class="category" selected="false" data-selected="false">First</div>
```

And now add some lines to your Javascript:

```
console.log($(this).attr('data-selected'));
console.log($(this).attr('selected'));
```

[(jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/lonesomeday/SE7FB/9/)

Surprising things happen. The first line logs `false`, as you expect. The second line logs `selected`. Clearly <s>the browser (Chrome in my case, I haven't tested others yet)</s> jQuery (per Blue Skies' comment) is doing what it would do with, say, an `option` element, and making the value of the `selected` attribute the string `selected`, no matter what the actual contents are.

The solution? Don't use attributes in ways contrary to how they were intended. Follow the specifications, and your life will be more joyful. HTML5 provides `data-*` attributes, which you can use to your heart's content.

Comment: If the code is changed to use the boolean constants `true` and `false`, instead of strings, and if the tests are similarly changed to just check truthiness, then it works (sort-of).

Comment: @Pointy "sort of" covers a multitude of Javascript sins!

Comment: Ha ha indeed.  The "sort-of" means that it toggles between "selected" and `undefined`.

Comment: It's not the browser. It's jQuery messing with the value. jQuery messes with `data-` attributes by automatically parsing them as JSON, hence the boolean. For the non-data attribute, jQuery is setting it to the string `"selected"` irrespective of its value. Neither behavior shows up if you use native methods. You'll get the expected string value even though they're not valid attributes.

Comment: ...I guess the JSON parsing is just if you use `.data()`. The `false` is coming back as a string from `data-selected`.

Comment: @BlueSkies Thank you, that's interesting.